# XML - IndexError: list index out of range при попытке обратится к дочернему элементу

Tags: python, xml

Когда пытаюсь получить доступ к дочернему элементу через индекс массива(el_child[i].tag) получаю IndexError: list index out of range, что не так?

Мой код:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('out16.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
parent = root.iterfind('.//root/Big_Images')
for el in parent:
    i = 0
    result = len(el.getchildren())
    el_child = el.getchildren()
    for el_child in el:
        while i < result:
            el_child[i].tag = "Big_Images" + str(i)
            i = i + 1

tree.write('out20.xml')
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте отладочные печати:

```
for el in parent:
    i = 0
    el_child = el.getchildren()
    result = len(el_child)
    print("len=", result)
    for el_child in el:
        while i < result:
            try:
                el_child[i].tag = "Big_Images" + str(i)
            except IndexError as n:
                print(n, " ", i)
            i = i + 1
```

И всё станет ясно.

Впрочем, ответ оказался довольно очевидным. Вы переопределяете переменную. 
Это что за чепуха:

```
el_child = el.getchildren()
    for el_child in el:
```

Вы понимаете, что это **разные** переменные (*el_child*) ? И длина **первого** *el_child* никак не связана с индексацией **второго** *el_child*.

Comment: кусок вывода из терминала:

Comment: `len= 5
list index out of range   0
list index out of range   1
list index out of range   2
list index out of range   3
list index out of range   4
len= 9
list index out of range   0
list index out of range   1
list index out of range   2
list index out of range   3
list index out of range   4
list index out of range   5
list index out of range   6
list index out of range   7
list index out of range   8
len= 4
list index out of range   0
list index out of range   1
list index out of range   2
list index out of range   3`

Comment: То-есть он может посчитать количество дочерних елементов, но не может обратится к ним по индексу =(

Comment: @Кевин  Я подправил ответ.

Comment: Аааа, извиняюсь что так сглупил. После долгих изменений и использования кода забыл убрать for...

Answer (score 0):

В конечном у меня итоге вышел такой вот код:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
parent = root.iterfind('.//root/Big_Images')
for el in parent:
    i = 0
    el_child = el.getchildren()
    result = len(el_child)
    try:
        while i < result:
            try:
                el_child[i].tag = "Big_Images" + str(i)
            except IndexError as n:
                pass
            i = i + 1
    finally:
        pass

tree.write('out.xml')
```

Собирает по индексу дочерние элементы родителя и переименовывает их добавляя номер индекса к имени. Обрабатывает весь файл размером 50 мегабит где то за 8 секунд. То что надо.

Большое спасибо за помощь =)